# Remove tags from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am using a library to process a text and give back the output as XML. Next I want to load the xml and extract some nodes out of it. The problem is that the library creates some open tags without a closing one. Something like this :

```
<wi num="610" entity="PERSON">OAZ</wi><somestringhere> <wi num="611" entity="PERSON">Stedman</wi>
```

Error : The 'somestringhere' tag on line 1 pos-xxx doesn't match the end tag of .

If the tags that it's creating was constant I would have been able to remove it. But these strings keep changing. Doing it manually is not feasible. How do I remove such tags from xml?

Comment: Why do you call such text "XML"? - this is really just text with some XML-like tags. If you can't fix library and can't produce XML yourself - consider to use HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack to read that text into DOM tree and build XML from that... ("Run away" is real answer in this case, but I doubt it is acceptable  for SO :) )

Comment: Since the XML that library produces is invalid I don't think you can manipulate it using C# as you wouldn't be able deserialize it in the first place. I think your best bet would be finding the unclosed tags using regular expressions and removing them manually. [This](http://concepts.waetech.com/unclosed_tags/) looks like a nice resource for finding the unclosed tags

Comment: If you can, use a different library

Comment: If this is really the output of the library and you won't get anything better, you need to build your own parsing function. <text seems to open the element, </text> seems to close it. Use your brain, doesnt seem too complicated...